# Character added in custom font

Tags: fonts, symbols, characters, font-encodings

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
% ttf2tfm custom.ttf -p T1-WGL4.enc
\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{custom}{m}{n} #1 }}

! \# \$ \% \& ( ) * + , . /\\
\customfont{! \# \$ \% \& ( ) * + , . /}

\end{document}
```

is working for **ES03.TTF**. But

[image]

**^** , **`**  and **~** character is not working or I couldn't do that. May you help me?

Related to: http://math.stanford.edu/~jyzhao/latexfonts.php

Related to: https://edu.casio.com/education/fontset/ (Natural Textbook Diplay Models -> fx-ES PLUS series -> fx-ES series)

---

**ShreevatsaR's SOLUTION**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
% ttf2tfm custom.ttf -p T1-WGL4.enc
\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{custom}{m}{n} #1 }}
\textasciicircum \textasciitilde \char0\\
\customfont{\textasciicircum \textasciitilde \char0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

That's what I wanted.

Comment: Add the **\textasciicircum** and  **\textasciitilde**

Comment: For `^`, backtick and `~`, does it work if you use `{\char94}`, `{\char96}` and `{\char126}` respectively? And if so, is that all you need (is that an answer to your question)? (Edit: For the backtick you may need `{\char0}` instead of `{\char96}`: see [Wikipedia page on T1 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cork_encoding&oldid=790743194).)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, I'm checking.

Comment: Not the problem, but don't define your font command like that! So you started with a TTF font, correct? Then you ran `ttf2tfm custom.ttf -p T1-WGL4.enc`. What output did you get? And what did you do with the files? Is your font entirely symbols? Can you freely edit and/or convert it? Because a type1 font would be easier to work with and is especially easy for symbols. But the T1 encoding isn't appropriate for symbols. Maybe this is all off-base because I'm not clear what your custom font is.

Comment: Arbitrary symbol fonts are the easiest to set up. For type1, you don't need an encoding. For TTF, an arbitrary encoding will do. So if you are trying to install a symbol font of this kind (you just need access to the characters in isolation - as if they were dingbats, say), you don't want to mess around with T1.

Comment: Is it one of the Casio font sets you want to install? If so, which?

Comment: The instructions you linked to are really awful. Sorry, but they are terrible in so many ways. It is frightening to think what some of the grateful commentators there will produce by way of typographical monstrosities as a result. You wouldn't, if it worked. But the instructions are bad for different reasons in your case.

Comment: TTF is a little trickier. By 'arbitrary' encoding, I mean font-specific. Either the font lies and the encoding is kind of random, or you need a custom encoding. But this is not hard to do. It looks to me like you can't convert the fonts, if they're truetype. That's too bad, but not the end of the world, by any means.

Comment: @cfr, I can not catch your writing speed. You are obviously very knowledgeable about this.

Comment: What OS are you using? I have a tendency to think aloud in comments. Sorry.

Comment: @cfr, I'm using Ubuntu 16.10. Do not get it wrong. But this is very important to me. I take advantage of your knowledge in matters I do not know. Please think aloud in my other questions.

Comment: OK. Good. Let me play a bit - it is a while since I did this. More later.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, The your solution is enough for me. How can I give you your bounty now?

Comment: Please wait for @cfr to post an answer; she's an expert on font and other stuff. I'll post an answer anyway, but it won't be the best/ right way.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Not sure about my expertise, but thanks. (My method does work and uses the `U` encoding, which is usual for symbol fonts.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Input

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,pgffor}
\usepackage{CasioES0}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\textbf{ES03}\smallskip

\foreach \i in {4,...,98} {\i: \ES1{\i} }
\bigskip

\textbf{ES04}\smallskip

\foreach \i in {4,...,98} {\i: \ES2{\i} }
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: Casio ES03 and ES04]

## Support Files

Set up a clean directory and copy the two font files `ES03.TTF` and `ES04.TTF` there.

Now make a `.tex` file there with the following content and compile it. (You can then delete the file - its purpose is only to write a bunch of files to the directory.)

```
\begin{filecontents}{ES03-drv.tex}
\input fontinst.sty
\needsfontinstversion{1.926}
%:substitutions
%bold for bold extended
\substitutesilent{bx}{b}
\substitutesilent{b}{m}
%:record transformations for later map file creation
\recordtransforms{ES03-rec.tex}
        \transformfont{ES03-8r}{\reencodefont{8r}{\fromafm{ES03}}}
        \input reglyph-ES03.tex
        \installfonts
                \installfamily{U}{ES03}{}
                \installfont{ES03-u}{ES03-8rr}{txtfdmns,ornaments}{U}{ES03}{m}{n}{}
                \installfontas{ES03-u}{U}{ES03}{m}{sc}{}
                \installfontas{ES03-u}{U}{ES03}{m}{it}{}
                \installfontas{ES03-u}{U}{ES03}{m}{sl}{}
                \installfontas{ES03-u}{U}{ES03}{m}{si}{}
        \endinstallfonts
\endrecordtransforms
\bye
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ES04-drv.tex}
\input fontinst.sty
\needsfontinstversion{1.926}
%:substitutions
%bold for bold extended
\substitutesilent{bx}{b}
\substitutesilent{b}{m}
%:record transformations for later map file creation
\recordtransforms{ES04-rec.tex}
        \transformfont{ES04-8r}{\reencodefont{8r}{\fromafm{ES04}}}
        \input reglyph-ES04.tex
        \installfonts
                \installfamily{U}{ES04}{}
                \installfont{ES04-u}{ES04-8rr}{txtfdmns,ornaments}{U}{ES04}{m}{n}{}
                \installfontas{ES04-u}{U}{ES04}{m}{sc}{}
                \installfontas{ES04-u}{U}{ES04}{m}{it}{}
                \installfontas{ES04-u}{U}{ES04}{m}{sl}{}
                \installfontas{ES04-u}{U}{ES04}{m}{si}{}
        \endinstallfonts
\endrecordtransforms
\bye
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ES03-map.tex}
\input finstmsc.sty
\resetstr{PSfontsuffix}{.ttf}
\adddriver{dvips}{ES03.map}
\adddriver{pltotf}{ES03-pltotf.sh}
\input ES03-rec.tex
\donedrivers
\bye
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ES04-map.tex}
\input finstmsc.sty
\resetstr{PSfontsuffix}{.ttf}
\adddriver{dvips}{ES04.map}
\adddriver{pltotf}{ES04-pltotf.sh}
\input ES04-rec.tex
\donedrivers
\bye
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reglyph-ES03.tex}
\relax
\reglyphfonts
        \renameglyph{orn0}{.notdef}
        \renameglyph{orn1}{.null}
        \renameglyph{orn2}{CR}
        \renameglyph{orn3}{space}
        \renameglyph{orn4}{exclam}
        \renameglyph{orn5}{quotedbl}
        \renameglyph{orn6}{numbersign}
        \renameglyph{orn7}{dollar}
        \renameglyph{orn8}{percent}
        \renameglyph{orn9}{ampersand}
        \renameglyph{orn10}{quotesingle}
        \renameglyph{orn11}{parenleft}
        \renameglyph{orn12}{parenright}
        \renameglyph{orn13}{asterisk}
        \renameglyph{orn14}{plus}
        \renameglyph{orn15}{comma}
        \renameglyph{orn16}{hyphen}
        \renameglyph{orn17}{period}
        \renameglyph{orn18}{slash}
        \renameglyph{orn19}{zero}
        \renameglyph{orn20}{one}
        \renameglyph{orn21}{two}
        \renameglyph{orn22}{three}
        \renameglyph{orn23}{four}
        \renameglyph{orn24}{five}
        \renameglyph{orn25}{six}
        \renameglyph{orn26}{seven}
        \renameglyph{orn27}{eight}
        \renameglyph{orn28}{nine}
        \renameglyph{orn29}{colon}
        \renameglyph{orn30}{semicolon}
        \renameglyph{orn31}{less}
        \renameglyph{orn32}{equal}
        \renameglyph{orn33}{greater}
        \renameglyph{orn34}{question}
        \renameglyph{orn35}{at}
        \renameglyph{orn36}{A}
        \renameglyph{orn37}{B}
        \renameglyph{orn38}{C}
        \renameglyph{orn39}{D}
        \renameglyph{orn40}{E}
        \renameglyph{orn41}{F}
        \renameglyph{orn42}{G}
        \renameglyph{orn43}{H}
        \renameglyph{orn44}{I}
        \renameglyph{orn45}{J}
        \renameglyph{orn46}{K}
        \renameglyph{orn47}{L}
        \renameglyph{orn48}{M}
        \renameglyph{orn49}{N}
        \renameglyph{orn50}{O}
        \renameglyph{orn51}{P}
        \renameglyph{orn52}{Q}
        \renameglyph{orn53}{R}
        \renameglyph{orn54}{S}
        \renameglyph{orn55}{T}
        \renameglyph{orn56}{U}
        \renameglyph{orn57}{V}
        \renameglyph{orn58}{W}
        \renameglyph{orn59}{X}
        \renameglyph{orn60}{Y}
        \renameglyph{orn61}{Z}
        \renameglyph{orn62}{bracketleft}
        \renameglyph{orn63}{backslash}
        \renameglyph{orn64}{bracketright}
        \renameglyph{orn65}{asciicircum}
        \renameglyph{orn66}{underscore}
        \renameglyph{orn67}{grave}
        \renameglyph{orn68}{a}
        \renameglyph{orn69}{b}
        \renameglyph{orn70}{c}
        \renameglyph{orn71}{d}
        \renameglyph{orn72}{e}
        \renameglyph{orn73}{f}
        \renameglyph{orn74}{g}
        \renameglyph{orn75}{h}
        \renameglyph{orn76}{i}
        \renameglyph{orn77}{j}
        \renameglyph{orn78}{k}
        \renameglyph{orn79}{l}
        \renameglyph{orn80}{m}
        \renameglyph{orn81}{n}
        \renameglyph{orn82}{o}
        \renameglyph{orn83}{p}
        \renameglyph{orn84}{q}
        \renameglyph{orn85}{r}
        \renameglyph{orn86}{s}
        \renameglyph{orn87}{t}
        \renameglyph{orn88}{u}
        \renameglyph{orn89}{v}
        \renameglyph{orn90}{w}
        \renameglyph{orn91}{x}
        \renameglyph{orn92}{y}
        \renameglyph{orn93}{z}
        \renameglyph{orn94}{braceleft}
        \renameglyph{orn95}{bar}
        \renameglyph{orn96}{braceright}
        \renameglyph{orn97}{asciitilde}
        \renameglyph{orn98}{quotedblright}
        \renameglyph{orn99}{quoteright}
        \renameglyph{orn100}{circumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn101}{CR}
        \reglyphfont{ES03-8rr}{ES03-8r}
\endreglyphfonts
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reglyph-ES04.tex}
\relax
\reglyphfonts
        \renameglyph{orn0}{.notdef}
        \renameglyph{orn1}{.null}
        \renameglyph{orn2}{CR}
        \renameglyph{orn3}{space}
        \renameglyph{orn4}{exclam}
        \renameglyph{orn5}{quotedbl}
        \renameglyph{orn6}{numbersign}
        \renameglyph{orn7}{dollar}
        \renameglyph{orn8}{percent}
        \renameglyph{orn9}{ampersand}
        \renameglyph{orn10}{quotesingle}
        \renameglyph{orn11}{parenleft}
        \renameglyph{orn12}{parenright}
        \renameglyph{orn13}{asterisk}
        \renameglyph{orn14}{plus}
        \renameglyph{orn15}{comma}
        \renameglyph{orn16}{hyphen}
        \renameglyph{orn17}{period}
        \renameglyph{orn18}{slash}
        \renameglyph{orn19}{zero}
        \renameglyph{orn20}{one}
        \renameglyph{orn21}{two}
        \renameglyph{orn22}{three}
        \renameglyph{orn23}{four}
        \renameglyph{orn24}{five}
        \renameglyph{orn25}{six}
        \renameglyph{orn26}{seven}
        \renameglyph{orn27}{eight}
        \renameglyph{orn28}{nine}
        \renameglyph{orn29}{colon}
        \renameglyph{orn30}{semicolon}
        \renameglyph{orn31}{less}
        \renameglyph{orn32}{equal}
        \renameglyph{orn33}{greater}
        \renameglyph{orn34}{question}
        \renameglyph{orn35}{at}
        \renameglyph{orn36}{A}
        \renameglyph{orn37}{B}
        \renameglyph{orn38}{C}
        \renameglyph{orn39}{D}
        \renameglyph{orn40}{E}
        \renameglyph{orn41}{F}
        \renameglyph{orn42}{G}
        \renameglyph{orn43}{H}
        \renameglyph{orn44}{I}
        \renameglyph{orn45}{J}
        \renameglyph{orn46}{K}
        \renameglyph{orn47}{L}
        \renameglyph{orn48}{M}
        \renameglyph{orn49}{N}
        \renameglyph{orn50}{O}
        \renameglyph{orn51}{P}
        \renameglyph{orn52}{Q}
        \renameglyph{orn53}{R}
        \renameglyph{orn54}{S}
        \renameglyph{orn55}{T}
        \renameglyph{orn56}{U}
        \renameglyph{orn57}{V}
        \renameglyph{orn58}{W}
        \renameglyph{orn59}{X}
        \renameglyph{orn60}{Y}
        \renameglyph{orn61}{Z}
        \renameglyph{orn62}{bracketleft}
        \renameglyph{orn63}{backslash}
        \renameglyph{orn64}{bracketright}
        \renameglyph{orn65}{asciicircum}
        \renameglyph{orn66}{underscore}
        \renameglyph{orn67}{grave}
        \renameglyph{orn68}{a}
        \renameglyph{orn69}{b}
        \renameglyph{orn70}{c}
        \renameglyph{orn71}{d}
        \renameglyph{orn72}{e}
        \renameglyph{orn73}{f}
        \renameglyph{orn74}{g}
        \renameglyph{orn75}{h}
        \renameglyph{orn76}{i}
        \renameglyph{orn77}{j}
        \renameglyph{orn78}{k}
        \renameglyph{orn79}{l}
        \renameglyph{orn80}{m}
        \renameglyph{orn81}{n}
        \renameglyph{orn82}{o}
        \renameglyph{orn83}{p}
        \renameglyph{orn84}{q}
        \renameglyph{orn85}{r}
        \renameglyph{orn86}{s}
        \renameglyph{orn87}{t}
        \renameglyph{orn88}{u}
        \renameglyph{orn89}{v}
        \renameglyph{orn90}{w}
        \renameglyph{orn91}{x}
        \renameglyph{orn92}{y}
        \renameglyph{orn93}{z}
        \renameglyph{orn94}{braceleft}
        \renameglyph{orn95}{bar}
        \renameglyph{orn96}{braceright}
        \renameglyph{orn97}{asciitilde}
        \renameglyph{orn98}{Adieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn99}{Aring}
        \renameglyph{orn100}{Ccedilla}
        \renameglyph{orn101}{Eacute}
        \renameglyph{orn102}{Ntilde}
        \renameglyph{orn103}{Odieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn104}{Udieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn105}{aacute}
        \renameglyph{orn106}{agrave}
        \renameglyph{orn107}{acircumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn108}{adieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn109}{atilde}
        \renameglyph{orn110}{aring}
        \renameglyph{orn111}{ccedilla}
        \renameglyph{orn112}{eacute}
        \renameglyph{orn113}{egrave}
        \renameglyph{orn114}{ecircumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn115}{edieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn116}{iacute}
        \renameglyph{orn117}{igrave}
        \renameglyph{orn118}{icircumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn119}{idieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn120}{ntilde}
        \renameglyph{orn121}{oacute}
        \renameglyph{orn122}{ograve}
        \renameglyph{orn123}{ocircumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn124}{odieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn125}{otilde}
        \renameglyph{orn126}{uacute}
        \renameglyph{orn127}{ugrave}
        \renameglyph{orn128}{ucircumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn129}{udieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn130}{dagger}
        \renameglyph{orn131}{degree}
        \renameglyph{orn132}{cent}
        \renameglyph{orn133}{sterling}
        \renameglyph{orn134}{section}
        \renameglyph{orn135}{bullet}
        \renameglyph{orn136}{paragraph}
        \renameglyph{orn137}{germandbls}
        \renameglyph{orn138}{registered}
        \renameglyph{orn139}{copyright}
        \renameglyph{orn140}{trademark}
        \renameglyph{orn141}{acute}
        \renameglyph{orn142}{dieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn143}{AE}
        \renameglyph{orn144}{Oslash}
        \renameglyph{orn145}{plusminus}
        \renameglyph{orn146}{yen}
        \renameglyph{orn147}{mu}
        \renameglyph{orn148}{ordfeminine}
        \renameglyph{orn149}{ordmasculine}
        \renameglyph{orn150}{ae}
        \renameglyph{orn151}{oslash}
        \renameglyph{orn152}{questiondown}
        \renameglyph{orn153}{exclamdown}
        \renameglyph{orn154}{logicalnot}
        \renameglyph{orn155}{florin}
        \renameglyph{orn156}{guillemotleft}
        \renameglyph{orn157}{guillemotright}
        \renameglyph{orn158}{ellipsis}
        \renameglyph{orn159}{nbspace}
        \renameglyph{orn160}{Agrave}
        \renameglyph{orn161}{Atilde}
        \renameglyph{orn162}{Otilde}
        \renameglyph{orn163}{OE}
        \renameglyph{orn164}{oe}
        \renameglyph{orn165}{endash}
        \renameglyph{orn166}{emdash}
        \renameglyph{orn167}{quotedblleft}
        \renameglyph{orn168}{quotedblright}
        \renameglyph{orn169}{quoteleft}
        \renameglyph{orn170}{quoteright}
        \renameglyph{orn171}{divide}
        \renameglyph{orn172}{ydieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn173}{Ydieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn174}{currency}
        \renameglyph{orn175}{guilsinglleft}
        \renameglyph{orn176}{guilsinglright}
        \renameglyph{orn177}{daggerdbl}
        \renameglyph{orn178}{periodcentered}
        \renameglyph{orn179}{quotesinglbase}
        \renameglyph{orn180}{quotedblbase}
        \renameglyph{orn181}{perthousand}
        \renameglyph{orn182}{Acircumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn183}{Ecircumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn184}{Aacute}
        \renameglyph{orn185}{Edieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn186}{Egrave}
        \renameglyph{orn187}{Iacute}
        \renameglyph{orn188}{Icircumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn189}{Idieresis}
        \renameglyph{orn190}{Igrave}
        \renameglyph{orn191}{Oacute}
        \renameglyph{orn192}{Ocircumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn193}{Ograve}
        \renameglyph{orn194}{Uacute}
        \renameglyph{orn195}{Ucircumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn196}{Ugrave}
        \renameglyph{orn197}{circumflex}
        \renameglyph{orn198}{tilde}
        \renameglyph{orn199}{macron}
        \renameglyph{orn200}{cedilla}
        \renameglyph{orn201}{Scaron}
        \renameglyph{orn202}{scaron}
        \renameglyph{orn203}{brokenbar}
        \renameglyph{orn204}{Eth}
        \renameglyph{orn205}{eth}
        \renameglyph{orn206}{Yacute}
        \renameglyph{orn207}{yacute}
        \renameglyph{orn208}{Thorn}
        \renameglyph{orn209}{thorn}
        \renameglyph{orn210}{minus}
        \renameglyph{orn211}{multiply}
        \renameglyph{orn212}{onesuperior}
        \renameglyph{orn213}{twosuperior}
        \renameglyph{orn214}{threesuperior}
        \renameglyph{orn215}{onehalf}
        \renameglyph{orn216}{onequarter}
        \renameglyph{orn217}{threequarters}
        \renameglyph{orn218}{index218}
        \renameglyph{orn219}{index219}
        \renameglyph{orn220}{index220}
        \renameglyph{orn221}{index221}
        \renameglyph{orn222}{index222}
        \renameglyph{orn223}{index223}
        \renameglyph{orn224}{index224}
        \renameglyph{orn225}{index225}
        \renameglyph{orn226}{index226}
        \renameglyph{orn227}{HT}
        \renameglyph{orn228}{CR}
        \reglyphfont{ES04-8rr}{ES04-8r}
\endreglyphfonts
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{CasioES0.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{CasioES0}[2017/08/24 v1.0 CasioES0 CFR]
\RequirePackage{pifont}
%%Adjusted by cfr in line with gtmacfonts
%%We don't want to add the map file through updmap because only pdftex can use truetype fonts.
\pdfmapfile{+CasioES0.map}
\Pifont{ES03}
\Pifont{ES04}

\newcommand*{\eschar}[1]{\Pisymbol{ES03}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\esplus}[1]{\Pisymbol{ES04}{#1}}

\newcommand*\ES{}
\gdef\ES#1#2{%
        \ifcase #1      \relax
                \or     \eschar{#2}%
                \or     \esplus{#2}%
        \fi}

\endinput
%% end CasioES0.sty
% vim: set nospell:
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ornaments.etx}
%% Copyright 2008 Clea F. Rees
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Clea F. Rees.
%
% This work consists of all files listed in manifest.txt.
\relax
\encoding
        \setstr{codingscheme}{ORNAMENTAL ENCODING}
        \setslot{orn0}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn1}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn2}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn3}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn4}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn5}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn6}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn7}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn8}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn9}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn10}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn11}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn12}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn13}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn14}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn15}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn16}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn17}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn18}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn19}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn20}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn21}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn22}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn23}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn24}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn25}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn26}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn27}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn28}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn29}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn30}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn31}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn32}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn33}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn34}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn35}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn36}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn37}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn38}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn39}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn40}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn41}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn42}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn43}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn44}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn45}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn46}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn47}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn48}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn49}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn50}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn51}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn52}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn53}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn54}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn55}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn56}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn57}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn58}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn59}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn60}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn61}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn62}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn63}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn64}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn65}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn66}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn67}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn68}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn69}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn70}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn71}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn72}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn73}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn74}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn75}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn76}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn77}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn78}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn79}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn80}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn81}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn82}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn83}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn84}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn85}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn86}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn87}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn88}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn89}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn90}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn91}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn92}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn93}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn94}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn95}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn96}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn97}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn98}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn99}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn100}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn101}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn102}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn103}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn104}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn105}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn106}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn107}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn108}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn109}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn110}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn111}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn112}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn113}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn114}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn115}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn116}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn117}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn118}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn119}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn120}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn121}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn122}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn123}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn124}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn125}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn126}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn127}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn128}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn129}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn130}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn131}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn132}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn133}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn134}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn135}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn136}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn137}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn138}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn139}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn140}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn141}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn142}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn143}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn144}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn145}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn146}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn147}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn148}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn149}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn150}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn151}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn152}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn153}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn154}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn155}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn156}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn157}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn158}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn159}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn160}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn161}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn162}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn163}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn164}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn165}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn166}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn167}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn168}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn169}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn170}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn171}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn172}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn173}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn174}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn175}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn176}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn177}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn178}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn179}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn180}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn181}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn182}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn183}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn184}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn185}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn186}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn187}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn188}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn189}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn190}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn191}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn192}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn193}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn194}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn195}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn196}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn197}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn198}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn199}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn200}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn201}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn202}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn203}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn204}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn205}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn206}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn207}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn208}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn209}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn210}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn211}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn212}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn213}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn214}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn215}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn216}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn217}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn218}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn219}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn220}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn221}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn222}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn223}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn224}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn225}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn226}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn227}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn228}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn229}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn230}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn231}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn232}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn233}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn234}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn235}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn236}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn237}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn238}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn239}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn240}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn241}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn242}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn243}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn244}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn245}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn246}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn247}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn248}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn249}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn250}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn251}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn252}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn253}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn254}\endsetslot
        \setslot{orn255}\endsetslot
\endencoding
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{CasioES0.map}
ES03-8r ES03 <[8r.enc <ES03.ttf " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont "
ES04-8r ES04 <[8r.enc <ES04.ttf " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont "
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Nothing to say.
\end{document}
```

Then

```bash
mv ES03.TTF ES03.ttf
mv ES04.TTF ES04.ttf
ttf2afm ES03.ttf > ES03.afm
ttf2afm ES04.ttf > ES04.afm
tex ES03-drv.tex
tex ES04-drv.tex
pltotf ES03-8r.pl
pltotf ES04-8r.pl
pltotf ES03.pl
pltotf ES04.pl
vptovf ES03-u.vpl
vptovf ES04-u.vpl
tex ES03-map.tex
tex ES04-map.tex
cat *.map > CasioES0.map
```

You need `ornaments.enc`, `CasioES0.map`, `CasioES0.sty` and the `.vf`, `.tfm` `.ttf` and `.fd` files. The other `.map` files and the `.tex`, `.etx`, `.mtx`, `.pl`, `.vpl`, `.sh` and the usual `.log` files etc. may be deleted.

Comment: I'm sorry you had to do a lot of things. You have spent a lot of effort. But it is very meaningful for beginners like me. Perfect working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about what `ttf2tfm custom.ttf -p T1-WGL4.enc` does. But if you look at the [T1 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cork_encoding&oldid=790743194), it has:

- Character `^` at position 94 (same as its ASCII value)
- Character `~` at position 127 (same as its ASCII value)
- Character `` ` `` at position 0: what it has at position 96 (ASCII value of the backtick) is instead the character `‘`, which is the character (that is encoded in Unicode as) [U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://codepoints.net/U+2018).

You can tell TeX to pick up whatever glyph it has at position *n* of a particular font, by saying `\char` followed by the number *n*. Thus, you can write `{\char94}`, `{\char127}` and `{\char0}` for the above characters respectively.

All this assumes that the font has indeed been encoded in the [T1 encoding](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/t1.htm) (which is what you seem to have ended up with somehow). As @cfr points out, this probably doesn't make sense for a font that has so little overlap with the set of characters that the T1 encoding is meant to cover. In fact, you could use *any* ad-hoc encoding with the glyphs mapped to arbitrary positions within the font, and use `{\char N}` with the appropriate values of N to get your desired characters from the font. And it makes sense to do such a thing, if you have a lot of characters that are not in T1.

Comment: I promised to give you bounty, but cfr's response is more comprehensive. If I give the bounty to cfr, would I have done wrong against you?

Comment: No :-) Please give it to @cfr.

Comment: Almost no font is T1-encoded as is. The reason it works reasonably well for ES03 is that Casio have called the characters 'a', 'b', 'c' and so on, even though they are not those characters at all. However, some of the characters in ES04 appear to be named in ways which T1 won't pick up e.g. `ordfeminine` and `logicalnot`. On the other hand, a lot of these apparent characters don't appear to actually exist, so I'm not sure that matters. What matters more is that, e.g., you really don't want typing `fi` to give you whatever happens to be in the fi ligature slot.

Comment: @Özgür I really don't care about the bounty.

Comment: But something like 'numbersign' isn't in T1, but rather in TS1, so if you want the character Casio put there, the T1 approach won't work. The advantage of the U encoding is you can use `pifont` and it doesn't expect anything to be anywhere in particular, doesn't include ligatures etc.